# Android emulator goes blank

Tags: android

Whenever i add this piece of code in my OnCreateView of fragment my emulator goes blank??
i have one activity after a button press it gets blank coz oher activity containing this fragment is called.

```
    DataBaseOperations hell = new DataBaseOperations(getActivity());
    SQLiteDatabase db = hell.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic};
    Cursor cur = db.query(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    byte[] b = null;
    Bitmap bp;
    while(cur.moveToFirst()){
        b = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic));
    }
    if(b.length>0){
        bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0,b.length);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.pro);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bp);
        cur.close();
        db.close():
        hell.close();
    }
```

any Idea?
here is log

> 12-26 19:50:25.575 2254-2304/com.example.umerasif.chattris
> W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
> 0xa36f3080, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>
> 12-26 19:50:27.048 2254-2254/com.example.umerasif.chattris I/Choreographer: Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> 12-26 19:50:36.286 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris
> W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.476ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:40.474 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.136ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:41.186 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.585ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:42.202 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 27.538ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:42.238 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.985ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:42.264 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.645ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:42.504 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 27.413ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:42.807 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 51.063ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:45.711 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 87.361ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:50.384 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.067ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:51.522 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.241ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:51.714 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.284ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:53.007 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.363ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:55.816 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.416ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:57.813 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.389ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:58.432 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 103.759ms
>
> 12-26 19:50:59.915 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 70.891ms
>
> 12-26 19:51:02.105 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 1.098s
>
> 12-26 19:51:03.178 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 346.129ms
>
> 12-26 19:51:05.353 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.087ms
>
> 12-26 19:51:05.830 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.031ms
>
> 12-26 19:51:06.347 2254-2260/com.example.umerasif.chattris W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.843ms

Comment: Put the db operations in an AsyncTask. It looks intensive at the first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting too many tasks inside the `onCreateView()`. The `onCreateView()` method is best used for initializing your views.

Try putting that code inside the `onActivityCreated` instead of `onCreateView`. Also, it would be better if you do the image loading inside an `Asynctask` to avoid unresponsive application.

Also, it might not be the problem of your code. The emulator you are using might be too slow to load your interface.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Yupe am trying through AsyncTask  if it solves i'll mark it answer.

Comment: To make it look better, put a placeholder image on the imageViews while the loading is still not finished.